# How do I create mongoose unique index with specific value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have collection named `TradeRequest` with the following schema

```
const TradeRequestSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["opened", "rejected", "accepted"],
    default: "opened"
  },

  _requester: {
    required: true,
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
  },

  _requestedBook: {
    required: true,
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
  }
});
```

My database should have only **one open request** for a book by any person.
So I added a unique index like so -

```
TradeRequestSchema.index({_requester: 1, _requestedBook: 1, status: 1}, {unique: true});
```

Problem is this prevents some data to be entered in the database which should be allowed.

For example it prevents my database to have following documents which is fine for my use case -

```
{_id: 1, _requester: 12345, _requestedBook: 9871212, status: "opened"}
{_id: 2, _requester: 12345, _requestedBook: 9871212, status: "opened"}
```

But it also prevents the following which is wrong for my use case.

For example if my database already has following documents -

```
{_id: 3, _requester: 12345, _requestedBook: 9871212, status: "closed"}
{_id: 4, _requester: 12345, _requestedBook: 9871212, status: "opened"}
```

I cannot change request with id `4` to `closed` now which is wrong.

Basically what I want is to have a single `opened` request for a `book` but multiple `closed` requests.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongodb has many types of indices like unique indices, sparse indices and partial indices. Your case doesn't need just the unique index, it needs [unique partial index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/). 
Try creating something like -

```
db.<<collectionName>>.createIndex(
{_requester: 1, _requestedBook: 1, status: 1},
{unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { "status" : "opened" }}
)
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.